# Passing data to mdDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, material-design, angular-material

Main listing page has edit button. Which opens details of the edited row.
**Way-1:** Now, if I set "ctrl.parent.q_details.client_location" it is bind with parent listing controller and it works as 2-way binding and automatically changes the values as in the edit box changes, Which is not requirement here.

Here just I want to display and allow edit values in inputbox. Not want to get changed in parent controller.

► Following is the code in parent controller to call mdDialog

```
$mdDialog.show({
                locals:{parent: $scope},                
                clickOutsideToClose: true,                
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',                
                templateUrl: 'quotation/edit/',//+edit_id,
                controller: function () { this.parent = $scope; },
            });
```

► Following is code of the popup mdDialog.

```
<md-dialog aria-label="">
    <div ng-app="inputBasicDemo" ng-controller="deliverController" layout="column">
        <form name="" class="internal_note_cont">           
            <md-content class="md-padding">             
                <md-input-container class="md-input-has-value" flex>
                    <label>Client Name</label>
                    <input ng-model="qe.client_name" required >
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container flex>
                    <label>Client Location</label>
                    <input required ng-model="ctrl.parent.q_details.client_location">
                </md-input-container>                   
            </md-content>
        </form>
        <div>           
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="" required ng-model="ctrl.parent.q_details.recid">  
</md-dialog>
```

**Way2:** second way is sending the value directly from DB without binding to ng-model of Dialog controller(deliverController).

```
]).controller("deliverController", ["$scope", "$filter","$http","$route","$window","$mdDialog",
    function ($scope, $filter,$http,$route,$window,$mdDialog) {
        $scope.qe.client_name = '12345'; // just to test.        
    }
```

This is giving error of undefine $scope.qe .

**So ultimately, I am not able to send data to mdDialogue and display them and allow edit them as normal way.
Please anyone experienced angular guy help me. I am new to angular.
I am trying different ways since 2 days.**

Comment: You can use ng-bind to set up a one time binding. You could also a service to pass data between the parent and child.

Comment: Have you tried with `preserveScope: true` ?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

This guy always has the right answer: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/455#issuecomment-59889129

In short:

```
$mdDialog.show({
            locals:{dataToPass: $scope.parentScopeData},                
            clickOutsideToClose: true,                
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',                
            templateUrl: 'quotation/edit/',//+edit_id,
            controller: mdDialogCtrl,
        });

var mdDialogCtrl = function ($scope, dataToPass) { 
    $scope.mdDialogData = dataToPass  
}
```

Pass the variable using the locals attribute in the passing object. These values will be injected into the controller **not the $scope**. Also passing the entire $scope of the parent might not be such a good idea as it defeats the isolated scope paradigm.

Comment: If mdDialogData is changed in mdDialogCtrl, will the change be reflected in $scope.parentScopeData? I have a use case which needs to pass in an object of current scope to mdDialogCtrl and the changes to that object in mdDialogCtrl should be catched in outside scope. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it does reflect, if you are passing a object reference via the locals, it does reflect, though i would expect it to isolate and not modify the parent's scoped data directly, strange..!

Comment: Any idea how to do this without using $scope?

Comment: Should there be a comma at the end of the object literal passed in .show? Specifically the line that says "mdDialogCtrl," - Seems like this shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 5):

**HTML**

```
<md-button ng-click='vmInter.showDialog($event,_dataToPass)'>
<i class="fa fa-custom-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</md-button>
```

**Js**

```
    function _showSiebelDialog(event,_dataToPass) {

        $mdDialog.show({
                locals:{dataToPass: _dataToPass}, //here where we pass our data
                controller: _DialogController,
                controllerAs: 'vd',
                templateUrl: 'contentComponents/prepare/views/Dialog.tmpl.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: event,
                clickOutsideToClose: true

            })
            .then(
                function(answer) {},
                function() {

                }
            );
    };

function _DialogController($scope, $mdDialog,dataToPass) {
console.log('>>>>>>> '+dataToPass);
}
```

Comment: how can I pass  value to calling function again in 'answer' parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.showPrompt = function(yourObject) {
$mdDialog.show({
    templateUrl: 'app/views/your-dialog.tpl.html',
    locals: {
        callback: $scope.yourFunction // create the function  $scope.yourFunction = function (yourVariable) {
    },
    controller:  function ($scope, $mdDialog, callback) {
        $scope.dialog.title = 'Your title';
        $scope.dialog.abort = function () {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };
        $scope.dialog.hide = function () {

            if ($scope.Dialog.$valid){
                $mdDialog.hide();
                callback($scope.yourReturnValue, likes the return of input field);
            }
        };
    },
    controllerAs: 'dialog',
    bindToController: true,
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    escapeToClose: true
});
```

};

Answer (score 1):

**The ES6 TL;DR way**

Create a controller with a scope variables on the fly:

```
let showDialog = (spaceApe) => {
    $mdDialog.show({
        templateUrl: 'dialog.template.html',
        controller: $scope => $scope.spaceApe = spaceApe
    })
}
```

Voilà, `spaceApe` can now be used in the dialog template

```
<md-dialog>
    <md-dialog-content>
        <span> {{spaceApe | json}} </span>
    <md-dialog-content>
<md-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
        confirmNewData = function() {
        let self = this;
        this.$mdDialog.show({                
            templateUrl: '/dist/views/app/dialogConfirmAFEData.html',
            controllerAs: "ctrl",                                
            controller: $scope => $scope = { $mdDialog: self.$mdDialog, 
                                             data: self.FMEData, 
                                             cancel: function() { this.$mdDialog.cancel(); }, 
                                             confirm: function() { this.$mdDialog.hide(); }  
                                           },
            clickOutsideToClose: false
        }).then(function() {
            // User Accepted!!
            console.log('You accepted!!!');
        }, function() {
            // User cancelled, don't do anything.
            console.log('You cancelled!!!');
        });
    };
```

And in the view...

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Start New AFE" style="min-width: 50%;">
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h2>GIS Data...</h2>          
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-dialog-content>
        <div layout="column" layout-padding>
            <li/>Lease: {{ ctrl.data.LEASE }}    
            <li/>Reservoir: {{ ctrl.data.RESERVOIR }}    
        </div>
    </md-dialog-content>

    <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
      <md-button class="md-button" ng-click="ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</md-button>
      <md-button class="md-button" ng-click="ctrl.confirm()">Yes</md-button>                
    </md-dialog-actions>
```