# AngularJS materials, Ruby on rails, $mdDialog

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, angular-material

I have a question. How to display on a pop-up window  the information from the previous window. I have this code. It is my main html page

```
<body ng-app = "smartDeals" ng-controller = "smartDealsController as controller" >
<div class = "text">

    <md-card md-theme="{{ 'dark-grey'}}">
<h1>Pizza Exemple</h1>
</md-card>
    <div class='md-padding' layout="row" layout-wrap>
        <md-card md-theme="{{ 'dark-grey'}}" style="width: 350px;" ng-repeat="pizza in controller.pizzas">
                <%= image_tag('6.jpg', style: "height: 250px; width: 350px") %>

          <md-card-content>
            <h2>{{pizza.name}}</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
          </md-card-content>
          <div class="md-actions" layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                    <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAdvanced($event)" flex="100" flex-gt-md="auto">
         Buy
     </md-button>
          </div>

        </md-card>
      </div>
</div>




<%=yield%>

</body>
```

It is my controller

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('smartDeals', ['ngMaterial','ngMessages']);

app.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('dark-grey').backgroundPalette('grey').dark();
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('dark-orange').backgroundPalette('orange').dark();
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('dark-purple').backgroundPalette('deep-purple').dark();
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('dark-blue').backgroundPalette('blue').dark();
});
app.controller('smartDealsController',function($scope,$mdDialog,$mdMedia){
  var web3 = new Web3();
  this.pizzas = pizzas;

  $scope.showAdvanced = function(ev) {
      $mdDialog.show({
        controller: function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.hide = function() {
      $mdDialog.hide();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $mdDialog.cancel();
    };

    $scope.answer = function(answer) {
      $mdDialog.hide(answer);
    };
  },
        templateUrl: 'solution_controller/index',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose:true,
        fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
      })
      .then(function(answer) {
        $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
      }, function() {
        $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
      });
    };



});
    var pizzas = [
      {
        name: 'Vegetariana',
        price: 400,
        description: 'Very good pizza!',
        images: [
          "assets/images/1.png",
          "assets/images/1.png",
          "assets/images/1.png"
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Quattro Formaggi',
        price: 300,
        description: 'Very good pizza!',
        images: [
          "assets/images/1.png",
          "assets/images/1.png",
          "assets/images/1.png"
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Maltija (Maltese)',
        price: 300,
        description: 'Very good pizza!',
        images: [
          "assets/images/1.jpg",
          "assets/images/1.jpg",
          "assets/images/1.jpg"
        ],
      }
    ];
})();
```

And pop-up window

```
<md-dialog ng-app = "smartDeals" ng-controller = "smartDealsController as controller" >
  <form>
    <md-dialog-content>
      <div class="md-dialog-content">
        <h2>{{pizza.name}}</h2>
    </md-dialog-content>

    <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
      <span flex></span>
      <md-button ng-click="hide()">Hide</md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </form>
</md-dialog>
```

I want to display on a pop-up window the information of only one pizza, to which the user clicked. I think I need some way to save the variable, which after clicking on the button will be pizza index entry of an array. But I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data to mdDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240772/passing-data-to-mddialog)

Comment: @PatrykŁucka agreed. You just need to give your `$mdDialog` call a pizza (That's weird, said like that ...)